# Optimal database insert query for element position

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

I've got a set of elements (roughly between 50-250) that I can drag/drop around. Now, once the drag/drop is done, I'd like to save the element's new position. Not so much of an issue, but I also need to update the position of all elements that are now before the dragged element.(give them a -1 position). It's simple enough when the move is between the first few elements, but when it's towards the end, I don't want to be making 200 requests, or have to do a `foreach` and write an overly long SQL statement

I'd like to know what would be the best approach for doing the SQL request.

I'm using Laravel 4 with Eloquent.

Thanks

Comment: What about `Element::whereIn('id', array(1, 2, 3))->decrements('position');`?

Comment: Ill try that right away, if good ill ask that you post it as an answer to I can vote you up

Comment: sorry,theres no whereIn in eloquent. Trying to find a replacement

Comment: Actually, there is. `All methods available on the query builder are also available when querying Eloquent models.`, from Laravel Docs.

Answer (score 0):

A drag and dropped element, so i suppose you need to store bidemensional coordinates like x and y of your element.
So you probably need a quadtree instead of using a database

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30535/A-Simple-QuadTree-Implementation-in-C

Comment: This looks more like sequential order, rather than X and Y coordinates.

Comment: yep, it's just sequential, from position 1 to n